# DFPlayer for Writing to SD Card

Tags: arduino-uno, library, sd-card, audio, sd

Can you use the DFPlayer to write to the SD card?
Link for DFPlayer: https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/DFPlayer_Mini_SKU:DFR0299

Here's the goal of my project. I have a button that, when pressed, should a- play a song off an SD card that is hooked up to the DFPlayer and b- should log "button is pressed" to the SD card. Unfortunately, the DFPlayer library doesn't seem to have any functions for this, and I wasn't sure how to see whether the DFPlayer has the functionality to support writing onto an SD card. Are there modules that are Read-only for SD cards? If so, is the DFPlayer one of them?

PS - I'm using an Arduino Uno, 
Thank you so much for your help! I am a complete novice for SD cards, so any help you give would be very much appreciated!

Comment: In short: no. The clue is in the name: "DFPlayer". It's a player. That's all it is.

Comment: whats wrong with the standard Arduino SD library? It should be able to read and write from an SD card

Comment: @esoterik, not on the DFPlayer board

Comment: why not use a second SD card? use the standard SD library with another card reader.

Comment: Thanks @Majenko, esoterik, and Juraj! I wanted to avoid buying a second sd card and reader if possible and use the DFPlayer to store information to the SD cars, but if that's not possible like you all are saying, I will go ahead and buy a new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the DFPlayer cant write that data to the SD card. The Arduino has some non volatile memory of its own built in though. Theres 1K of EEPROM for the UNO. Notes on how to use it here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM
If you can get what you need to done in 1K and its not important to your project that you be able to unplug the SD card and put it in another reader, then perhaps thats a nice, simple solution...